# External access to Node.JS app, within Docker container

Tags: node.js, docker, portforwarding

i have a Node app running within a Docker container, hosted on Elastic Beanstalk (single instance). The docker has port 3000 exposed to access the app within the docker, and I can 'curl 172.17.0.32:3000/test' from the host which returns the expected response.

The problem I have is accessing this port externally using the elastic beanstalk url. i.e

http://XXXXXX-env.elasticbeanstalk.com:3000/test

This will time out.. can anyone recommend how to gain access to this port externally?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check this for reference
http://victorlin.me/posts/2014/11/26/running-docker-with-aws-elastic-beanstalk

see what your docker ps command returns.

The ip you have shared looks like private ip address of the docker service used for internal network. You have to enable a bridge between your host and docker container by supplying -p 3000:3000 to the run command and finally enable the app in your elastic console.